# For loop or while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which function definition is more efficient in Python, even though they do the same task? I.e when should we use a `for` loop and when should we use a `while` loop?

```
def count_to_first_vowel(s):
    '''  (str) -> str
    Return the substring of s up to but not including the first vowel in s. If no vowel
    is present, return s.
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('hello')
    'h'
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('cherry')
    'ch'
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('xyz')
    xyz
    '''
    substring = ''
    for char in s:
        if char in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            return substring
        substring = substring + char
    return substring
```

or

```
def count_to_first_vowel(s):
    '''  (str) -> str
    Return the substring of s up to but not     including the first vowel in s. If no vowel
    is present, return s.
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('hello')
    'h'
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('cherry')
    'ch'
    >>> count_to_first_vowel('xyz')
    xyz
    '''
    substring = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(s) and not s[i] in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        substring = substring + s
        i = i + 1
    return substring
```

Comment: Oh the code display got messed up :( how do I fix that for future reference?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I gave you an edit that you can accept. StackOverflow uses Markdown syntax. If you put -three- four spaces at the beginning of a line, it is counted as a part of a code block. You can also use the editor for this.

Comment: *"Which function definition is more efficient in Python"* - why not test them (e.g. with `timeit`) and find out? You can also look at the bytecode they compile to with `dis`. But this seems like pointless micro-optimisation. And, FYI, SO **is not a forum**.

Comment: @DaymonSchroeder four spaces, right?

Comment: I think it will depending very much on what goes on in the conditional statement. In general I think there is no one **better** option but in your example there may be. Also consider maintenance versus performance, if performance isn't absolutely critical it may be best to not worry about that, and instead write what is easier for you maintain later when you don't remember what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop evaluates the length once, and operates knowing that. The `while` loop will have to evaluate `len(s)` each loop. There may be more overhead in accessing the individual index of the string each time the `while` statement gets evaluated too.

If the `while` loop is recalculating something like `len()` each time, I *think* it would be more efficient to use `for`. Both of them have to test at least one condition each loop though.

Rewriting the `while` loop to use a save variable like `len = len(s)` may remove that extra bit and make them extremely close. This is more true when you consider that your `for` loop is executing a second internal loop.